# Database design for school fee processing

Tags: database-design, relational-database, rdbms, database-schema

I need suggestions on a database design.

I am currently working on designing a DBMS for a school. After designing courses and exams tables, now I have come to fees module.

here is what I have done so far.
I have created 4 tables which are described as below:

```
fee_type
-------------
fee_type_id PRIMARY KEY

fee_type    TYPE OF FEE (MONTHLY, WEEKLY,ANNUAL,ONE TIME)

fees
-------------
fees_id PRIMARY KEY

fee_heading  (eg. TUITION FEE,LAB FEE, HOSTEL FEE,SPORTS FEE)

amount       (CURRENT CHARGE OF THE FEE, could change with time)   

class_id     (GRADE ID, GARDE 4, GARDE 5, GRADE 6)

fee_type    TYPE OF FEE (MONTHLY, WEEKLY,ANNUAL,ONE TIME)

archived     (FEE HEADING ARCHIVED FOR USE)

fee_student
-------------
fee_id     (RELATED fee_id (FK))

student_id (RELATED student_id(FK))

effective_from (DATE FROM WHEN THE FEE APPLIES TO THE STUDENT)

amount  (CHARGE AT THE TIME OF FEE ASSIGNMENT (applicable to particular student))

discount (DISCOUNT HONORED TO STUDENT IF ANY)

status (ACTIVE OR INACTIVE)

transaction
---------------
id PRIMARY KEY

date (date and time when transaction takes place)

fee_id (PAYMENT FOR)

student_id ({TO BE} PAID BY)

amount ( AMOUNT PAID/APPLIED)

description

cr ( yes or no)

dr (yes or no)

remarks
```

Transaction table will store all the payments by student as well as all the amount charged for that student.

I am thinking of storing amount charged to students in transaction table according to fee_type. that means, if the fee is of type WEEKLY, one record per week will be automatically added to the transaction table and the amount is marked as debit (or credit , whatever) .

Hope it makes sense.

Am I on the right path to design database ?

Your comments and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Bishnu

Comment: Thanks High for reading the post. I am just asking comments on the design if the design is correct and what can be done to make the design better. I am going to update the question.

Comment: Hi @BishnuPaudel,  I am also working over a same project, could you please provide me a database you have design for the student fee management. it is my humble request.

Comment: Im on the same project. please share your design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is on the right track.  A couple of comments:

- `fees.fee_type` should probably be `fees.fee_type_id` - assuming you want to use a natural join nomenclature.
- Instead of `transaction.cr` and `transaction.dr` you should establish a convention for the sign of the amount and just have a single amount field which is interpreted as credit or debit based on which side of zero the amount is on.  Your current design allows an amount to be both credit and debit (unless you have a constraint that forbids this).
- One thing your design won't accomodate is **"unapplied cash"**.  In your current design, a payment from a student must be for a specific `fee_student`.  What if a student makes an advanced deposit, receives a scholarship, or simply writes one cheque for multiple fees (tuition, lab, sports)?  In your current model, you don't track that single (or unapplied) payment.  You should have a transaction table that accepts payments from students and then use an intersection table (your current `transaction` table) to apply payments to specific fees.  This allows you to have unpaid balances and unapplied amounts - both of which are common in real-world accounts payable applications.

Comment: Thanks Joel for clear explanation. I really liked the idea of having a separate table to record payments from student. I will give it a shot. Regarding scholarship, I am thinking of having a separate table for scholarship which will store details about scholarship. Up on receiving a scholarship, the discount column in fee_student table will be updated to hold percentage of discount received by that student. How does it sound? CHEERS

Comment: @BishnuPaudel - It would be good to have a table for scholarships.  If your scholarships are granted as discounts to fees then using the `fee_student.discount` column is a great idea.  If you sometimes have cash awards then you can do it similar to a payment.

Comment: Can you share me the database design

Comment: cand you elaborate the unapplied cash and intersection table. i dont get it

Comment: @Sras I don't have a database design, I was commenting on the design in the original question, so you can use that as the basis. The problem with unapplied cash is that in the real world there is not a 1:1 correspondence between sending an invoice and getting payments. The design should have one table (new to the design above) for payments from students and then the `transaction` table in the OP's design would be an intersection between the payment and the `fee_student` showing what the payment was used for.  It might help to talk to a bookkeeper to understand how this works in business.

Comment: could you show me the relationship based on this design

Comment: @Sras The OP's `transaction` table should not have `student_id` instead it should have `payment_id` which points to a new `payment` table that has these columns: `id`, `date`, `student_id`, `amount` and any other columns you want, like description/remarks. The payment table records the fact that money came in from a student. The (modified) transaction table records that all or some of that money was used to pay for specific fees.

Comment: @JoelBrown, I have come another requirement. which im not sure how to design. In case, school fee is 35$ per month, 100$ for payment 3 months. Then, if the student pay in Janurary for 3 months, 100$. We want to generate revenue report - which 1/3 of 100$ for Jan, Feb and March respectively. How could I design to accomuldate this requirement. Thank you.

Comment: @JoelBrown, I think to add column Amount, Month, Year to transaction table. which the amount is split by getting amount from payment table divide by the number of month.

Comment: @Sras this is really more of a question of revenue accounting procedures rather than database design. You want to have revenue reports that recognize revenue as it is realized on a monthly basis. Sometimes this is done inside an accounting system. However, if you wanted to do it in your database then you could create one transaction per month that breaks a course fee down into monthly installments and then these three transactions would be linked to three payments (one each) if the student pays monthly or 1 payment if the student pays the whole amount at once.

Comment: @JoelBrown Thank you. I uploaded my db design to here https://ibb.co/GnzrzVm . Could you give me feedback on the design.

Comment: You are right. this can be done in QB system. But, this is requirement which data entered to get the revenue report

Comment: @Sras it looks OK to me. The only thing I would think about is whether to have `Transaction` point at `FeeStudent` instead of at `Fee`.  It may not make a difference because you can get to the same answer by going up through `Payment` to `Student`. I think it might be a little more direct to have StudentId in the `Transaction` - It all depends on how often your querying/reporting on transactions needs to include students in the results.

Comment: Right I will try to make changes based on your commment .What do you think when transaction is split by payment 33.33333 then it wonts be 100$ .... then there will be discrepancy data right ... how can I fix this

Comment: You seemed very knowledgeable! Can I have your email or telegram . I could ask for your recommendation on some point if you don’t mind ... or even request you for mentoring technical

Comment: @Sras you can ask questions on Stack Overflow where you can get help from many knowledgeable people.

Comment: @JoelBrown what about this "Right I will try to make changes based on your commment .What do you think when transaction is split by payment 33.33333 then it wonts be 100$ .... then there will be discrepancy data right ... how can I fix this"

Comment: @Sras in a database that deals with money you need to have processing which deals with rounding.  Your program logic which creates the three transaction splits needs to be sophisticated enough to apply 33.33 to each split and then work out that you're 0.01 short at the end and add that arbitrarily to one of the splits. You can decide on what convention you use for this, i.e. apply to the earliest, apply to the latest, etc.

Comment: @JoelBrown. Thank you. But I still could not get it clear yet.

Comment: @Sras, the program logic that splits a single payment of 100.00 into three parts needs to do these steps: (a) 100.00 / 3 = 33.33 (rounded to smallest precision of currency) (b) 100.00 - 3 * (33.33) = 0.01 is the rounding error for the split calculation and (c) the last split amount (or first, or whatever you decide) is now 33.33 + 0.01 = 33.34 to account for the rounding error.

Comment: @JoelBrown —— thank you . Quite clear now .

Comment: And do you think is it better to remove relationship between feestudent and transaction. 

Second, do you should I add day / month / year to transaction table .... if in case they want to get the income by specific date

Comment: What do you think how could I implement notification due date payment ? Shall I have one table specifically for notifications

Comment: @Sras - Dates should always be stored in a date field, even if you only care about the month for now. Later you may decide to care about the day level or semi-monthly or whatever. Just pick a convention for precision that you don't care about yet, e.g. always use 1st of the month (or whatever works for you).  Remove relationships that can be derived from lower level relationships (i.e. there is another path that will eventually get to the same place). It helps to avoid creating potential inconsistencies.

Comment: @Sras - Notifications are a totally different thing. They should be in a table with a relationship to the thing(s) that the notifications are for.  You could easily find yourself sending multiple notifications (advanced notice, notice of due date, past due notice, etc.)

Comment: @JoelBrown, thank. you are right for the date. 1st of month should be okay for this. ... Will be removing unnesary relationship.

Comment: @JoelBrown... For notification, I am going to add another due_date field to feestudent with the status Active/Inactive. My process will be ... when the student do the payment succesfully. there will be recorded of fee student added to the feestudent table. when the due date is reached. it will be changed to status inactive. WHAT DO YOU THINK?

Comment: @Sras I'm not necessarily a fan of adding a status flag. If the status can be calculated by other facts, like whether a matching payment is found in the database or what is the current system date compared to a transaction's date. I'm not sure I understand exactly why you want a status flag and what your business rules are for it, and it doesn't matter either way if I understand. My advice to you is don't make a flag with a value that can be easily calculated with a query. Flags should be used only when they capture an actual decision that is an input to the system (e.g. from a user)

Comment: @Joel Brown thank you sir ! Very nice suggestion. My business requirements is to get all list of students having due date . Or have to pay the fee in any specific month .... ... I believe adding status of payment ( paid , unpaid ,) would be better right

Comment: @Sras can you share you above db design if handy

Comment: @SandeepTiwari here i uploaded ibb.co/GnzrzVm .

Comment: @Sras but its (ibb.co/GnzrzVm) showing page doesn't exist, could you please see if you can manage

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also add column of Due Date of Fee in fee_student.

If the School have 10 thousand student how you will add paid information for all the students????

Comment: what do you mean by add paid information to 10k students